# How to define and use an integer value in Android resources?

Tags: android, android-resources

How does one specify an integer value in `xml` and retrieve that value in `Android` application?

Answer (score 20):

Do as follows:

1. Create **integers.xml** file in your project's `\res\values` folder. In the file create your `integer`:

   ```
   <resources>
       <integer name="your_integer">value</integer>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Use it as xml attribute. For example for `TextView`:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:maxLines="@integer/your_integer" />
   ```
3. Or use it programmatically

   ```
   int myint = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.your_integer);
   ```

Reference: [Integer resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer)